# Python 2.7 Tkinter Change Label text on button event

Tags: user-interface, button, python-2.7, tkinter

Im very new to Python(2.7) im learning GUI design(Tkinter) and keep running into different syntax/no **call** method/global name not defined errors when trying to implement a simple label text change from a Entry object on button click. Can someone show me the correct syntax for the action

```
from Tkinter import *
class Part3:

def __init__(self, parent):

    GUIFrame =Frame(parent,width= 300, height=200)
    GUIFrame.pack(expand = False, anchor = CENTER)
    entry = Entry(text="enter your choice")
    entry.place(x=65, y = 10)
    self.test = StringVar()
    self.test.set('''Hi, I'm a Label :)''')
    self.Label1 = Label(parent, textvariable = self.test)
    self.Label1.place(x = 85, y = 100)
    self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='edit',command=self.LabelChange)
    self.Button2.place(x= 80, y = 60)
    self.Button3 = Button(parent, text='exit', command= parent.quit)
    self.Button3.place(x= 160, y = 60)


def LabelChange(self):

    test = self.entry.get()
    self.Label1(test)


root = Tk()
MainFrame =Part3(root)
root.title('Input Test')
root.mainloop()
```

The Idea being on the 'edit' (button2) click, the text of Label1 is changed to the text of entry.

Comment: You need to fix the indentation of your example code. Also, I encourage you to _not_ start by using `place` -- using this will create GUIs with poor resize behavior. Take an hour or two to learn `pack` or `grid` -- there's a tiny learning curve but your GUIs will be much better for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
self.entry = Entry(text="enter your choice")
...
test = self.entry.get()
self.test.set(test)
```

I know most tutorials give examples using textvariables, but in most cases you don't need them. You can get and set the values in the widget without using textvariable. Textvariables are mostly useful for doing traces on variables. Variable traces are a somewhat advanced technique that you will rarely need.

Comment: test = self.entry.get()
    AttributeError: Part3 instance has no attribute 'entry'

Comment: @GeorgeDay: sorry about that. I failed to realize you weren't saving a reference to the entry widget. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No more errors thrown however the new code produces no effect on Label1

Comment: @GeorgeDay: sorry, my bad. I so rarely use textvariables that I forget they override the `text` attribute. I've updated my answer. You need to call `set` on the textvariable, giving it the value from the entry widget.

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *
class Part3:

def __init__(self, parent):

    GUIFrame =Frame(parent,width= 300, height=200)
    GUIFrame.pack(expand = False, anchor = CENTER)
    self.entry = Entry(text="enter your choice")    # this needs to be in self
    self.entry.place(x=65, y = 10)
    self.test = StringVar()
    self.test.set('''Hi, I'm a Label :)''')
    self.Label1 = Label(parent, textvariable = self.test)
    self.Label1.place(x = 85, y = 100)
    self.Button2 = Button(parent, text='edit',command=self.LabelChange)
    self.Button2.place(x= 80, y = 60)
    self.Button3 = Button(parent, text='exit', command= parent.quit)
    self.Button3.place(x= 160, y = 60)


def LabelChange(self):
    self.test.set(self.entry.get())

root = Tk()
MainFrame =Part3(root)
root.title('Input Test')
root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use a  .after command. For example:

```
     Lbl = Label(text='Hi')
     def change():
         Lbl.after(3000, lambda: Lbl.config(text="hola")
         # Or you can use the one below to remove delay.
         Lbl.config(text='hola')
        return change
     Btn = Button(command=change ())
     Lbl.pack()
     Btn.pack()
```